# compare two HashMap Integer and String

Tags: android, hashmap

I got two HashMaps with Strings and Integers and both of them carry "20" and 20
When i'm trying to compare them using toString() i always get inequality:

```
HashMap<String, String> vals = HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> nums = HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

if(nums.get(id).toString() == vals.get("num")) {
    Log.i(TAG, "DataBase.updateOrder(): number is the same");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "DataBase.updateOrder(): number has changed");
}
```

When i use Integer.valueOf() for String HashMap it works well and they are equal:

`if(nums.get(id) == Integer.valueOf(vals.get("num")))`

And of course the following record doens't work at all in the way i need:

`num.get(id).equals(vals.get("num"))`

So the question is why does my first bit of code not work (as i expected)?

Comment: are you using the same key for each entry of the hashmap?

Comment: actually no. nums keeps just IDs of records, and vals keeps values for one record, including its ID under "num" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this`.equals` in your compare the string.

```
if(nums.get(id).toString().equals(vals.get("num"))) {
    Log.i(TAG, "DataBase.updateOrder(): number is the same");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can compare if you parse the String to an int, then you have an integer comparison instead of an string comparison:

```
if(nums.get(id) == Integer.parseInt(vals.get("num"))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is rather simple:
when you compare by "==" you compare the objects' location in memory. If you want to be sure that "=="
is doing the right thing you need somehow to point one to the other (not the perfect way of saying). Equals on the other hands tries to compute the comparison of the objects' contents.
More about what I have just explained at the link below. 
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/ 
If you want tor read more about how to implement your own equals on your classes read here.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html 
I hope I answered to your question.